# If y = 3x - 6 what is the minimum product of x*y?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Ok I am not a mathematician and I got myself tripping on this question (which I think is not correctly formulated )

at first I thought "pfff thats easy its just an aslant line so I'll go to minus infinity on both sides and that would be my minimum product"

but if I remember correctly from school -infinity * -infinity = +infinity

and how could the minimum product of an equation like that be infinity since just by doing some over the top of my head calculation I could find quite a few x,y pairs from y = 3x - 6  of which the product is smaller than infinity!!

then I thought to to multiply everything with x and get xy = 3x^2 -6x and just find the minimum of 3x^2 -6 which is 1,-3 ....

but I can't make any inference from that since this may be the lowest point of that quadratic equation but these coordinates do not appear on the line 3x - 6...

So I am very confused.... is the question somehow not correct? what am I missing?

Comment: Do you know how to find a minimum of the expression $$3(x-2)x$$  With calclus or coordinate-geometry(parabola)  or some other method like AM-GM?

Comment: yea its 1-3 as I mentioned it above isnt it?  but I cant explain to my self how it correlates with the initial question

Comment: Point is that the correct solution you find $(1,-3)$ has no reason to be on the line. Why would it? You'll find the point on the curve $3x^2 - 6x$ where it belongs

Comment: why would it? because it is in the initial question we are looking about an x and y ON the line that have the minimum product... but I was wrong 1-3 is on the line 3x-6 as well.

Comment: That's a coincidence. You're searching the point $x,y$ on the line, but that you cannot expect that the maximum value taken by $xy$ is also on the line; that would be like asking the point $(x, xy)$ to be on the line $(x,y)$.. It only works when $x=1$, but not in general. Ask again if you're still confused

Comment: the value is the surface of the quadrat which begins from 0,0 and has a y side and an x side in our case the surface of that quadrat is -3 and one side is 1 and the other y. Since we are looking for a product we are looking essentially for a quadrat surface that must  have a common y and x with the line it self. I think I got it now but you try to confuse me :P

Answer (score 1):

Given $x$, the product is 
$$
x(3x-6)=3(x^2-2x)=3(x^2-2x+1-1)=3((x-1)^2-1)
$$
Since $(x-1)^2\ge0$, it should be clear that the minimum possible is $-3$, for $x=1$ and $y=-3$.

The trick is “completing the square”, that is, going from $x^2-2x$ to $x^2-2x+1-1=(x-1)^2-1$.

Comment: You probably didn't read  the question carefully,  that is a good way but the op already found the minimum and was confused by something else ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your answer and reasoning are by an large correct. There is no reason for that point to be on the line. The answer is $-3$, this is the minimum of the product. (It is attained when $x= 1$, but that's not strictly needed to answer the question.)

If you want to give a geometric sense to it all, you could consider the product as the area of the rectangle formed by a point on that line and the origin. But you'd have to account for the sign in a non-intuitive way. 
I think this is not really helpful in this case.